# locked:no search option returns locked answers anyway

Tags: support, search, locked-questions

The query [is:answer locked:no](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20locked%3ano) returns locked answers (e.g. [What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118)) despite the "locked:no" option.

Comment: This applies to all historically locked questions. The "locked" status is only on the question despite its effect being on all the answers as well.

Comment: But it doesn't apply to "normally" locked questions, apparently -- [bobince's famous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1204143) doesn't show up in my results.

Comment: That's because bobince's answer has a lock on it specifically. There's a normal lock both on the question and on the answer.

Comment: Sounds like implementation details leaking into the UI.  If I can't vote on/edit/comment on/etc an answer then it should be considered locked for purposes of the "locked:" search operator, regardless of whether or not it also has an extra special double-lock.